# I made csv file on the server - how can I let the client download this file?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have made csv on the server like this:

```
string Expath = @"d:\A.csv";
protected void Button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    FileStream FS = null;
    StreamWriter SW = null;
    try
    {
        FS = new FileStream(Expath, FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.ReadWrite, FileShare.ReadWrite);
        SW = new StreamWriter(FS, Encoding.Default);
        SW.WriteLine("Test");
        SW.WriteLine("1,2,3,4,5");
    }
    catch { }
    finally
    {
        if (SW != null)
        {
            SW.Close();
            FS.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

is it correct to make this file on `d:` on the server? if not where is better to place hem?

how do to that the client can download this file after he made it? (asp.net C#)

Comment: Don't have an empty `catch` block like that. A `try{}finally{}` is fine without it.

Comment: +1 Oded Yes *please* don't have an empty catch block

Comment: You could do either of these. First option In the catch section try logging the error to log files with Log4 net or through your own custom logging implementation. Second option take out the try catch and log errors from "void Application_Error(object sender, EventArgs e)" in global.asax

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could use this code to push the file to browser.

```
     private void PushToBrowser(string FilePath, byte[] Data)
    {
        HttpContext.Current.Response.Clear();
        HttpContext.Current.Response.BufferOutput = true;
        HttpContext.Current.Response.ClearContent();
        HttpContext.Current.Response.ClearHeaders();
        HttpContext.Current.Response.ContentType = @"application/csv";
        HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + Path.GetFileName(FilePath));
        HttpContext.Current.Response.OutputStream.Write(Data, 0, Data.Length);
        HttpContext.Current.Response.Flush();
        HttpContext.Current.Response.Close();

        File.Delete(FilePath);
    }
```

You could use the following code to convert you text data to byte array

```
byte[] Data = File.ReadAllBytes(FilePath)
```

I won't recommended keeping generated files outside the web directory, even though its possible to write to a directory outside the web root in  ASP.NET through [impersonation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xh507fc5%28v=VS.85%29.aspx), but its not at all recommended on production enviornment.

Comment: `File.Delete(FilePath);` deletes the file after it has been sent to the browser, right?
Just to make sure in case Gali doesn't want that to happen.

Comment: Yes you are right. Its better to clean up the file after pushing to the browser, so as to avoid filling up the server space with these temp files, unless business requirements explicitly specifies.

Answer (score 0):

Probably d:\ is not a so good place. If you have a web server running on that server, you have to see where the Virtual Directory of the site in which you intend publish the file is located, and then put the file somewhere here.

Answer (score 0):

When I have made files on the server, eg images I have saved to

```
Server.MapPath(@"~\" + sFilename)
```