# Build a stored procedure that will generate a CSV when a selection is made from a drop down menu

Tags: sql-server, csv, stored-procedures

I have a table in my database with employee details in it.

```
Employee ID (INT),
EmployeeType (Varchar10),
FirstName (VARCHAR 20),
Surname (VARCHAR 20),
DateOfBirth (smalldatetime),
AccountNum (VARCHAR 5),
JoingDate (smalldatetime)
```

I want a user to be able to select an `Employeetype` from the dropdown menu of "Types of Employee" in the CMS and for it then to generate a CSV (to download) without displaying the table of results in the CMS (this is because at the moment the result set is too large for the CMS page to handle).

How would I create a stored procedure to retrieve a table with the selected `EmployeeType` and for that to be automatically generated into a downloadable CSV file?

I was thinking a stored procedure behind a button would achieve this?

Comment: If you have a cms - you are talking about a web app. So you have to generate content server-side, that will be returned to the users browser, that they can then save somewhere on their machine. You should probably tag the question with your CMS - and probably drop the stored procedure tag.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4689599/i-made-csv-file-on-the-server-how-i-can-let-the-client-to-download-this-file - this is a C# example. But your CMS may be PHP, Java, Node.js, Python etc too. You have to understand how to setup the HTTP Headers for this kind of stuff - that part is common to all server languages. So if you know underlying language of your CMS - add that too.